# EF6 ObjectMaterialized causes SqlExceptions in tests

Tags: entity-framework-6

When subscribing to ObjectMaterialize

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized += (sender, e) => { /* Note, fails even when the handler is empty */ }
```

this works fine in production code. However, as soon as I add this, I get in tests exceptions:

```
Message: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

Removing that single line (ObjectMaterialized += .. ) resolves it again. I have been debugging, but cannot find the cause. Does anyone here happen to have encountered this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a doofus... This was in a test assembly that didn't have a ConnectionString, and apparently adding this handler causes a connection to be established when instantiating the DbContext.

So, if you have this problem: Add connection strings to your App.config of the test project.